# How do I use the jQuery selector string in the function I call?

Tags: jquery

```
$('.someClass').someFunc();

someFunc(){
   var thatClass = **???**;
}
```

I'm wondering how to get the string that I used in the jQuery call into the Function that I chain to it. Is there even a way?

Comment: Whaaat? You want to use a callback function on a custom plugin?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Do you want the string or the class name? Because you can use `$(this)` in your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use selector

```
var thatSelector = $(this).selector; //returns ".someclass"
```

Comment: note: if `this` is already a jQuery object (e.g : you are inside a plugin function ...) you don't need to wrap it in a `$(...)` call

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! The `.selector` syntax is what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As [Anton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18594188/86072) said : you can look at the `selector` property.

However, your jQuery selection may have been built using traversing functions (`.parent()`, `.eq()`, etc... ), or directly selecting html nodes. In most of those cases, the jQuery object will have an empty `selector` string :

```
var $divs = $('div.mine');
console.log( $divs.selector ); //prints 'div.mine'
var $children = $divs.children();
console.log( $children.selector ); //prints '' (empty string)
var $oneDiv = $( $divs[0] );
console.log( $oneDiv.selector ); //prints '' (empty string)
```